# Workaround for Grid incompatibility with Parent realtionships?

Tags: relationships, grid

I am developing a Tutoring service website: a school contacts the Tutoring service for a Student, the Tutoring service arranges a private Tutor.

Each school can log in and see the Students from their school placed with the Tutoring service.

Schools are members. The Students are channel entries.

Each School is the author of all of their Students’ entries. Using {author_id} ensures a school can only see its own Students.

There is a details page for each Student.

On the details page is the Tutor's schedule.

The Tutor's schedule channel is going to be authored by the Tutors.

There could be more than one Tutor per Student. The same Tutor could be assigned to more than one Student. Also, one Tutor can teach the same Student more than one subject.

I used a Grid field to set up the Tutor’s schedule.  (Day of Week - Start Time - End Time)

I have related the Tutor's schedule channel to the Student channel.

But it seems the only way I can get the Tutor's schedule into the Student channel is by putting this into the Student channel:

```
{parents channel="tutors_subjects_schedules"}

    <p>{parents:tutors_name}<p>
    <p>{parents:tutors_email}<p>
    <p>{parents:tutors_phone}<p>
    <p>{parents:subject}<p>
    <p>{parents:schedule:day} {parents:schedule:start_time} {parents:schedule:start_am_pm} {parents:schedule:end_time} {parents:schedule:end_am_pm}<p>
    <p>{parents:exceptions}<p>

{/parents}
```

My problem is all the fields comes in except the Grid fields. And from what I see in the EE 2.7.1 guide, it's an issue the Grid fields can't be used with parent relationship.

I am looking into using Matrix/Playa instead of EE's native Grid/Relationships, but I was wondering if there was another workaround for the probelm.

I'm not an expert with either EE or Relationships. :(

Thank you!

Comment: Wow that's quite a lot of stuff. Can you confirm a few things, like which channel do you make the relationship between Tutor and Student. Does the Tutor choose which student to apply a schedule to, or does the school apply the schedule to the Student?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, we have similar issue... that it relationship and grid field..?

Comment: I am sorry but I never received notification that questions were posted! I hope you were able to resolve your issues!